# adding and subtracting an element from array pointer

Tags: c++, c, arrays, pointers

I accidentally stumbled upon this question which says find the output of the following code-

```
char abc[14] = "C Programming"; 
printf("%s", abc + abc[3] - abc[4]);
```

I am seriously not understanding how the output is coming- rogamming
can somebody please explain me this?

Comment: It's technically undefined behaviour because the addition goes too far, but one of the ones that I've never seen break anything.

Comment: @chris not so. The entire expression is `abc + abc[3] + abc[4]` - nothing is out of bounds there.

Comment: @Kenney, `abc + abc[3]` is out of bounds, regardless of how the result is used. At least under a character system where r isn't a really low value.

Comment: @chris By that reason I can say `abc - abc[4]` is out of bounds. But then I'm ignoring part of the expression.

Comment: @Kenney, Addition associates left-to-right. It's `(abc + abc[3]) - abc[4]`. The intermediate result is out of bounds. Switching the subtraction and addition would have the same problem, but it would be out of bounds in the other direction. No one ever expects this to be UB, and like I said, I've never seen it break anything, but I'm speaking pedantically.

Comment: @chris: yes, in theory its undefined, but it works with every compiler and on every platform

Comment: @chris wrong. What's happening is that there is simple arithmetic of 3 numbers: the `abc` pointer (an integer), the `abc[3]` (an integer) and the `abc[4]` (an integer). This integer pushed on the stck for the printf call. No out of bounds array dereferencing  anywhere.

Comment: @ul90 this doesn't make it any less undefined. Far so many bugs have emerged late after publishing because Undefined Behavior worked for a while on every compiler on every platform... for a while...

Comment: @Kenney, There doesn't need to be a dereference. *If both the pointer
operand and the result point to elements of the same array object, or one past the last
element of the array object, the evaluation shall not produce an overflow; otherwise, the
behavior is undefined.* (N1570 §6.5.6/8, but it's there in some form in every standard version of C and C++ AFAIK)

Comment: @bolov: but it's working from the beginning of C and C++ until now... but you're right, it's very very bad style

Comment: @ul90 that's fine... if you write code you intend not to use never again in the future.

Comment: @ul90 That's saying: but I drove on red since I got my licence and I never got caught until now. What is the problem?

Comment: @ul90, no it is definitively not working on platforms that have segmented memory. These are rare nowadays (or not used with that feature) but the C standard still covers that possibility.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is very subtle, but the code exhibits **undefined behavior**. This is because the addition is done first, resulting in a pointer outside of the bounds of `abc`, which is undefined behavior, **even if it is not dereferenced**. The "correct" way would be to do the subtraction first.

```
char abc[14] = "C Programming"; 
printf("%s", abc + (abc[3] - abc[4]));
```

Even then, the result wouldn't be set in stone, as  there is no guarantee that ASCII encoding is used for chars. But as ASCII is ubiquitous used we will ignore this.

Other answers deal explain the *black magic* behind the code, so I won't repeat it here.

Answer (score 2):

`abc[3]` and `abc[4]` are just `char` values `'r'` and `'o'`. They can be used like other integral types. The value of `'r'` is (commonly) just the value of ASCII of character `r`.

So `abc + abc[3] - abc[4]` is not magical, it's just pointer arithmetic.

However, in this code `abc + abc[3]` is already out of index, so the code is invalid.

Comment: Not so - `abc[4]` must be subtracted.

Comment: @Kenney merely forming the pointer with `abc + abc[3]` is undefined behaviour, because it doesn't point into the array. In practive however, it works on all sensible architectures.

Comment: @Quentin -that's true, but the expression is NOT `abc + abc[3]` but `abc + abc[3] - abc[4]`.

Comment: @Kenney but operator associativity rules wtate that the leftmost addition (or subtraction) is done first. `abc[3] - abc[4] + abc`, for example, would not trigger UB.

Comment: You can't ignore part of the expression to say anything about the expression.

Comment: @Kenney yes we can, because the other part is itself an expression. Which triggers UB.

Comment: @Kenney Let's put it this way so you see it is indeed UB: `std::numeric_limits<long long>::max  + 10 - 11` That's UB!. So it is the example.

Answer (score 2):

`abc` is the start address of the `abc[14]` array (the address of `abc[0]`).
`abc[3]` is the 4th entry in the array which is the character `r` and `abc[4]` is the 5th entry in the array which is the character `o`. The ascii value for `r` is 114 and the ascii value for `o` is 111, so you add 114-111=3 to your array pointer.
Your output should be "rogramming"

But - as stated in the comments - it's very bad style and also could be undefined behaviour.